# How to copy file to Windows share (using command line) without asking for user's help, if possible at all?

Tags: macos, command-line, network-shares, smb

I need to copy a file from my OS X machine to a remote Windows share. Currently, I first use `open` and then `cp -f myFileName /Volumes/TheRemoteShareName/myFileDestinationName.txt"`.

Is there a way (using only command line) to copy the file without GUI?
I tried `mount_smbfs -W workgroup //user:password@SERVER/folder ./mntpoint` [as suggested here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line) but it made me retype password for some reason - so it's not a good solution cause it demands user to act and Im looking for a fully automated solution.

edit: i'm looking for a built in solution please... no extra installations.
edit: this question was not properly formulated (now edited)

Comment: Probably not.  cp supposes the file system be mounted,

Comment: is there another command perhaps?
my goal is to copy a file to shared folder programmatically (completely  programmatically)

Comment: I am an OS/2 user. Linux and apple are not my cup of tea, but i suspect that the file system must be open.  You could write a shell script to do this, and run it on demand from a desktop icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I saw this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020610225855377)

wrote this apple-script and its working (working from command line made me retype password for some reason - so I'm using the script).

`try
   mount volume "smb://user:password@server/sharePath"
end try`

thank u all

in link they suggested also to add this to startup items so u won't have to run script every time u startup...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done, but not with cp as it assumes both the source and destination file systems are mounted.

I would suggest using rsync as it excels at this type of task and can be programmed on command line from either the source or destination machine, or even from another machine altogether. It needs to be installed on both source and destination machines.

For Windows install cwRsync, osx comes with rsync as standard. You'll need to set up public/private key pairs so that the machines can authenticate with one another over SSH without requiring a password. Once that is configured you can use a command similar to this to sync the files:

rsync -avz /some/local/file/to/backup destination:/some/path/to/destination/

Watch out for correct use of trailing slashes on the source and destination paths, they have great significance.

Comment: thank you. that is a very good solution. however it creates Dependence in whether `rsync` is installed or not and i want a built in solution. im editing my question now...

Comment: In that case, can you clarify what you mean by "without mounting the remote share first"? You need access to the remote filesystem so that will have to be either by mounting it or some third-party access mechanism. 

Would an acceptable solution be to have a script that checks if the volume is already mounted, if not then mount it, copy the file, then unmount it?

Comment: yes @BlueC. this is a great idea! as long as I don't have to use/see the GUI at all... 
i finally found this: [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020610225855377) as a starting point. it's working!